# How to join different table some column?

Tags: sql

**Student Table 1**

```
ID      Name     Surname        School Number     Class Number   ClassBranch
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
113     Jane      Smith               19                4               A
121     John      Konl                42                5               B   
331     Albert    Smith               61                4               A
742     Jack      Ronal               52                5               B
759     Jan       Ronal               84                6               C
```

**Student Table 2**

```
ID     Name     Surname       School Number      Class Number   Class Branch
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
113    Jane     Smith              11               4             D 
151    John     Konl               18               4             D 
804    Albert   Smith              26               5             F 
605    Jack     Ronal              32               5             F 
785    Jan    Ronal               87               8              L
```

**Created Student Table**

```
ID    Name   Surname   School Number    Class Number    Class Branch        
--------------------------------------------------------------------
113   Jane   Smith      NULL                 NULL          NULL
151   John   Konl       NULL                 NULL          NULL
804   Albert Smith      NULL                 NULL          NULL
605   Jack   Ronal      NULL                 NULL          NULL
NULL  NULL   NULL        11                    4             D  
NULL  NULL   NULL        18                    4             D  
NULL  NULL   NULL        26                    5             F  
NULL  NULL   NULL        32                    5             F
```

**I want this table**

```
   ID    Name   Surname    School Number   Class Number   Class Branch

   113   Jane   Smith           11              4               D

   151   John   Konl           18              4               D

   804   Albert Smith          26              5               F

   605   Jack   Ronal          32              5               F
```

I want to Student **Table 1 ---> ID,Name,Surname**  and **Student Table 2 --> School Number,Class Number and ClassBranch** joın.But joın is not successful.Class Branch A and B removed and D,F is adding.

First table ID,Name,Surname (3 columns) and Second table School Number,Class Number,Class Branch join.

`Where` conditions:

- Removed column  -->   4 - A   AND 5 - B
- Adding  column  -->   4-  D   AND 5-  F

How can I write query?

Comment: Please show what you have tried so far.

Comment: How are the two tables related? There are no equal values between the two tables to join on. Do you want a UNION instead?

Comment: I want the rows not to be null.It could be a solution.

Comment: For a `join` between two tables to work, the tables need to have something in common, something that can connect each row of the one table to rows of the other table. The way you describe it, it is not possible to deduce how to join, since you haven't told us what the two tables have in common.

Comment: Based on what you want the desired output to be I agree that a UNION is more suited here. I am not sure why all the NULL's would be in there though?

Comment: Was thinking union as well, but then saw he wanted different columns for each table.

Comment: Where does school number 1 and 2 come from? That's not in either of the original tables.

Comment: Not all column joın.Only where condition column join.

Comment: *Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).*

Answer (score 1):

Now that you've completely changed the original tables, this should be a simple `JOIN`.

```
SELECT t2.id, t1.name, t1.surname, t2.SchoolNumber, t2.ClassNumber, t2.ClassBranch
FROM Student1 AS t1
JOIN Student2 AS t2 ON t1.name = t2.name AND t1.surname = t2.surname
```

[DEMO](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!9/0ec0b2/1)

Comment: I think this will give the result the OP gave as an example of what he didn't want..

Comment: I thought that was what he wanted.

Comment: I don't understand what you mean. Edit the question and add what you tried, along with the error message.

Comment: I don't see where you added 5 columns. But I updated the answer to show how you can select multiple rows with `OR`.

Comment: I'm currently in 8 rows and null fields not join.Is there any things else I can do?

Comment: I don't understand what you're asking. I think my answer does what you want.

Comment: I've added a sqlfiddle demo that shows that it gets the correct result.

Comment: I added the want table to the bottom of created table

Comment: OK, now it doesn't make any sense. How are the two tables related so that the School Number for Alex Alexus goes to John Konl in the result? Also, shouldn't Jane John be Jane Smith?

Comment: I want to change the data between the tables.How can I do?

Comment: Ok.Let's  assume the same people. Id,Name,Surname,Class Number are the same.How can I do join?

Comment: Then you join the tables `ON t1.id = t2.id`

Comment: ID,Name and Surname field are different.Only two tables class number values are the same.Is it possible to unify class branches when the are is changed.According the class branches 4-a,5-b fields are removed and 4-d,5-f is update.Can I make the join process according the class number value?

Comment: I don't understand your comment. The result you say you want shows that the name and surname are the same between the two tables, not different. Doesn't my query give the correct answer?

Comment: Thanks for this @Barmar. Look at this guy's history. All of his questions are "give me the code". I would keep coming back with garbage questions too after finding someone to answer. Great job.

Answer (score 0):

To get those results?

1) The complicated way. By joining them.

```
SELECT 
s2.ID, 
s1.Name, s1.Surname,
s2."School Number",  s2."Class Number", s2.ClassBranch
FROM Student1 AS s1
JOIN Student2 AS s2 ON (s2.Name = s1.Name AND s2.Surname = s1.Surname)
WHERE s1."Class Number" IN (4, 5);
```

2) The simple way, select only from the 2nd table

```
SELECT *
FROM Student2
WHERE "Class Number" IN (4, 5);
```

Test on SQL Fiddle [here](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!7/53ba0/1/0)

Comment: Thanks for this @LukStorms. Look at this guy's history. All of his questions are "give me the code". I would keep coming back with garbage questions too after finding someone to answer. Great job.